# How can I generate CDF from a large dataset in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, figure, cdf

I have 6 datasets each containing 10000 entries.

I want to plot their CDFs for comparison.

In MATLAB I am using the following code:

```
figure()
ksdensity(dataset1,'Support','positive','Function','cdf',...
          'NumPoints',5)
xlabel('Error')
ylabel('CDF')
```

But I am not sure, is it the right way or wrong? 
How can I do that?

I am getting the following figure. 
[image: This is my sample image and I want Marker point also]

Comment: Figure legend also not working on this figure.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
This has been made even easier with [`cdfplot()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cdfplot.html).

```
% MATLAB R2019a
% Example Data 
X = wblrnd(2,3,50000,1);
Y = wblrnd(3,2,50000,1);
Z = wblrnd(2.5,2.5,50000,1);
Data = [X Y Z]; 


figure, hold on
for k = 1:size(Data,2)
    h(k) = cdfplot(Data(:,k));
end
legend('show')
```

---

It looks like you've got the result you want except for the legend and markers. If you'd like more control of the plotting features, I'd suggest obtaining the necessary elements to plot from [`ksdensity`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html) using `[f,xi] = ksdensity(x)` then plotting separately.

[image: Example cumulative distribution functions.]

```
% MATLAB R2019a
% Example Data 
X = wblrnd(2,3,50000,1);
Y = wblrnd(3,2,50000,1);
Z = wblrnd(2.5,2.5,50000,1);
Data = [X Y Z];         

NumPointCDF = 5;       % Number of points to estimate CDF with

figure, hold on
for ii = 1:size(Data,2)  % for each column of Data
    [fii, xii] = ksdensity(Data(:,ii),'Support','positive','Function','cdf',...
          'NumPoints',NumPointsCDF);
    p(ii) = plot(xii,fii,'LineWidth',1.1,'Marker','.','MarkerSize',12);
end
legend('X','Y','Z')
```

Alternatively, you could just plot each first,

```
figure, hold on
for ii = 1:size(Data,2)  % for each column of Data
    [fii, xii] = ksdensity(Data(:,ii),'Support','positive','Function','cdf',...
          'NumPoints',NumPointsCDF);
    p(ii) = plot(xii,fii);
end
```

and then change the properties of each line later with `p(1).foo` (see here).

For example, one at a time: `p(1).Marker = 's'   % square`

Or all at once:

```
% Update all properties using the object
for ii = 1:size(Data,2)
    p(ii).Marker = '.';          % Adjust specific properties of p(ii) as needed
    p(ii).LineWidth = 1.2;
end
```

Reference:

1. [Graphics Object Properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics-object-properties.html)
2. [Access Property Values](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/access-and-modify-property-values.html)